# Why does get_legend_handles_labels() return empty lists when legend labels are added via ax.legend()

Tags: matplotlib

After the following common code:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [x for x in range(10)]
y = [math.sin(x) for x in x]
```

The following two code snippets produce the ***exact same*** plot:

```py
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(x,y,label='AAA')
ax.legend()
print('ax.get_legend_handles_labels() returns:\n',ax.get_legend_handles_labels())
plt.show()
```

```py
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.legend(labels=['AAA'])
print('ax.get_legend_handles_labels() returns:\n',ax.get_legend_handles_labels())
plt.show()
```

The print statement from the first snippet returns

```py
ax.get_legend_handles_labels() returns:
 ([<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x7fc32cbdfac0>], ['AAA'])
```

**but the second snippet gives**:

```py
ax.get_legend_handles_labels() returns:
 ([], [])
```

---

**Why does `get_legend_handles_labels()` return empty lists in the second case, yet the resulting plot is identical?**

---

Comment: My understanding is that the first example is set in the scatterplot and automatically takes over and displays it in the legend; the second one returns empty because the scatterplot has no label set. It then sets its own legend; you can understand it better if the first legend is `ax.legend(['BBB'])`.

Comment: I tried `ax.legend(['BBB'])` in case 1, and I see that the actual legend on the Axes is 'BBB' while `get_legend_handles_labels()` returns ['AAA'].  Here's the thing, what I really need is the list of handles.  Somehow `ax.scatter()` knew to which handle to apply the label that was passed in.  How can I get that list of artist handles *without passing in a label*?